# What exception does parseuser.SignUpAsync() throw?

Tags: c#, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

What exception does parseuser.SignUpAsync() throw?

It is not mentioned in the tutorial and I can't find it in API reference.

Comment: Shouldn't be hard to find out - create a test with s `catch (Exception ex)` block, call it with bad data (or whatever would be expected to throw an exception) and see what  the type of `ex` is.  Wouldn't be a bad unit test if you expect the behavior to change in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `ParseUser.SignUpAsync()` doesn't throw any exceptions anymore.

Look here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-dotNET/issues/10